# Query about meaning of "absolute units" for size of an order in Backtesting.py on XAU/USD market

Tags: pybacktest

Supposing that I am writing a strategy with Backtesting.py which I want to test against historical market data for XAU/USD. I would like to specify the size of new trades in absolute units, which means the size parameter should be set to a value greater than or equal to 1. So will the "absolute units" be US dollars, or troy ounces of gold, or will they be lots, where 1 lot is 100,000 troy ounces of gold?